# How to add meta in nuxt router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In vue, we defined meta like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'bar',
          component: Bar,
          // a meta field
          meta: { requiresAuth: true }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

But how do we define meta in nuxt?

Comment: There is an answer been accepted but bear in mind that when using Nuxt (in SSR mode), you don't get middleware to run anything initialy (pageload)...
I chose to disregard middleware alltogether in Nuxt.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `vue-router` `meta` as custom component property.
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1687#issuecomment-331870619

Simple example
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/2.x/examples/routes-meta

Answer (score 0):

I built a [Nuxt module](https://github.com/dword-design/nuxt-route-meta) that basically injects page variables into the `route.meta` property at build time. Then you can use it inside `this.extendRoutes` or to generate sitemap routes with [@nuxtjs/sitemap](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module).

Install it via `npm install nuxt-route-meta` and add it to your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  modules: [
    'nuxt-route-meta',
  ],
}
```

Add meta properties in a page:

```js
export default {
  auth: true,
  meta: {
    theme: 'water',
  },
}
```

And now you have the properties in `route.meta` in each route. You can for example check it by using `this.extendRoutes` inside a module:

```js
export default function () {
  this.extendRoutes(routes =>
    routes.forEach(route => {
      if (route.meta.auth) {
        // do something with auth routes
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: How can auth: true become part of meta. It is outside the {}?

Comment: It's the way the module is implemented. It adds all data inside the page object + the ones inside meta to route.meta.

Comment: I implemented it, but my route.meta is just {}.

Comment: @jolly Ah alright. It could be related to some feature used in the file that's not yet supported by nuxt-route-meta, but we could make it support it. Or it's some other small issue. I'd say best is to create an issue on https://github.com/dword-design/nuxt-route-meta/issues and link it here. So we do not debug stuff here on stack overflow :).